# How to send data back to apache server after getting information locally on the machine using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, post, web

I am attempting to gather data from my apache server from the local host connecting to it and sending back the data back to the server so that all others can see the information. Currently this is the code I have running on my server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=navigator.plugins.length; // store the total no of plugin stored
var txt="Total plugin installed: "+x+"<br/>";
txt+="Available plugins are->"+"<br/>";
for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
{
   txt+=navigator.plugins[i].name + "<br/>";
}
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

currently this script takes the information from the client and displays what plugins are present for that specific user. How would i have it so that the data is sent back to the server and basically have the web server create a page of all the data of anyone who has connected to the server? in essesnce I would be creating a log of everyone who connects to my server and display what plugins they have. The biggest issue i am having right now is getting the information back to the server.

Comment: You'd usually have something running on the server that can accept and store the data. That is much too broad for a Stack Overflow question, though - you'd have to learn a server-side language like PHP, Perl, Ruby, server-side JavaScript... there's many others, depending on what your server setup is offering. It's definitely too broad for here though.

Comment: I have a javascript function wrapped inside my html code. I am asking how i would send that data shown to the client back to the server, how is that question too broad? I'm asking how this would be implemented in javascript or another server-side language that I can wrap in my code.

Comment: Sending data back and forth is the very basic lesson you learn when starting with any server-side language. Just pick a language you can work with and go for it - you'll quickly find resources on how to do this. We can't pick a language for you without knowing what your server supports.

Answer (score 0):

Do an alert(txt); to check if txt has the correct value. Most likely it is not getting assigned a correct value or it might be crashing before that.